How to access the Paginator in Controller in Api Platform 4 after upgrading?
I followed the Upgrade Guide to upgrade Api Platform from version 3.4 to 4.0.
Before Api Platform 4.0, I was able to inject the Api Platform Paginator directly into my custom controller like this:
Entity Class:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            controller: MyCustomController::class,
        ),
    ],
)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MyEntityRepository::class)]
class MyEntity
{

}

Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class MyCustomController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(
        Paginator $data
    )
    {
        // Some logic
        return $data;
    }
}

However, after upgrading to Api Platform 4, I encounter the following error:
{
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "detail": "Cannot autowire argument $data of \"App\\Controller\\MyCustomController()\": it references class \"ApiPlatform\\Doctrine\\Orm\\Paginator\" but no such service exists.",
    "status": 500,
    "type": "/errors/500",
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Argument/ServiceLocator.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "getService",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}

From my understanding, ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator is no longer a service, which is why it cannot be injected.
How can I access the Paginator in Api Platform 4? I need to use it in my custom controller. Is there a new recommended approach to achieve this?

Try to inject PaginatorInterface instead of Paginator ?

I tried it but I got the same error
